# How to keep previous data in Leaflet Realtime

Tags: node.js, leaflet, gis

I am trying to use Leaflet realtime plugin (https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime), they mentioned in the documentation that we can keep previous updates by adding start:false in the constructor.

```
var map = L.map('map'),
    realtime = L.realtime({
        url: 'https://wanderdrone.appspot.com/',
        crossOrigin: true,
        type: 'json'
    }, {
        interval: 3 * 1000, start:false
    }).addTo(map);
```

Anyone have better  idea on how to do that ?

plnkr has a good demo:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/NmtcUa?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set `start: false`, automatic updates will be disabled. This means you will have to call the layer's `update` method yourself, providing any GeoJSON data you want to add or update; you can also remove added features with the `remove` method. These methods can be used if you want to use something other than server polling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code that I copied from plnkr while changed a little bit, because L.realtime inherit L.geoJson. And L.geoJson have 'layeradd'.

```
realtime.on('layeradd', function(e) {
var coordPart = function(v, dirs) {
        return dirs.charAt(v >= 0 ? 0 : 1) +
            (Math.round(Math.abs(v) * 100) / 100).toString();
    },
    popupContent = function(fId) {
        var feature = e.features[fId],
            c = feature.geometry.coordinates;
        return 'Wander drone at ' +
            coordPart(c[1], 'NS') + ', ' + coordPart(c[0], 'EW');
    },
    bindFeaturePopup = function(fId) {
        realtime.getLayer(fId).bindPopup(popupContent(fId));
    },
    updateFeaturePopup = function(fId) {
        realtime.getLayer(fId).getPopup().setContent(popupContent(fId));
    };

 map.fitBounds(realtime.getBounds(), {maxZoom: 3});

Object.keys(e.enter).forEach(bindFeaturePopup);
Object.keys(e.update).forEach(updateFeaturePopup);
});
```